# Fetch GL account from XML through automation script for Integration

Tags: python, xml, maximo

I have written a script on publish channel and would be triggered before processing. I have to fetch the GLaccount and when trying to do that it returns null value. The piece of code is
`irData.getCurrentData("GLDEBITACCT) or even this irData.getCurrentData("VALUE")`. I guess this is incorrect because in the XML the GL account appears something like below,

```
<GLDEBITACCT>
<VALUE>00.00000.00000.000000</VALUE>
<GLCOMP glorder="0">00</GLCOMP><GLCOMP glorder="1">00000</GLCOMP>
<GLCOMP glorder="2">00000</GLCOMP><GLCOMP glorder="3">000000</GLCOMP>
</GLDEBITACCT>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a getGL method in psdi.iface.mic.StructureObject . If you pass the GL component name it will fetch value.

Comment: yes it fetches the value however GLCOMP values are not present . The XML has only <GLDEBITACCT> and <VALUE>